# OLS: Show that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}_{i1}\hat{r}_{i1}=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}_{i1}\hat{u}_{i}=0$

Tags: multiple-regression, variance, least-squares

The following is stated in appendix 3A in Jeffrey Wooldridge book (5 edition page 114): Introductory Econometrics - A Modern Approach:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}_{i1}\hat{r}_{i1}=0
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\hat{x}_{i1}\hat{u}_{i}=0
$$

when he deduces the variance of the ols-estimates as a function of the $VIF_j$ (variance inflation factors):

$$
Var(\hat{\beta_{j}}) = \frac{\sigma^2}{SST_{j}(1-R_j^2)} = \frac{\sigma^2}{SST_{j}}VIF_j \text{  for  } j=1,2,..,k
$$

$\hat{r}_{i1}$ is the residual after regressing $x_1$ onto the other regressors ($SST_j$ and $R_j^2$ comes from that estimation when $j = 1,2,...,k$), and $\hat{u}_i$ is the residual after regressing y onto all the x-regressors. I understand that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i1}\hat{r}_{i1}=0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i1}\hat{u}_{i}=0$ from the first-order conditions.

Mr. Wooldridge does not deduce the variance of the $\beta_0$ (he show it for for the simple regression in chapter 2). I belive that it is (I can show all the derivation if somebody need to see it):

$$
Var(\hat{\beta_{0}}) = \sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{n}+
 \sum_{j=1}^{k} \bar{x}_j^2\frac{ VIF_j}{SST_{j}}\right)
$$
in the multiple case, but I have never seen somebody do this for the constant term.

1. Can somebody give me some guidance on how to show that the the two sums above is zero.
2. Can somebody please verify that the expression for $\beta_0$ is correct.
3. Why does not Wooldridge neither deduce it or show the expression for $\beta_0$ in the multiple regression when he show it for the simple one?

Thank you.